# Avoiding huge files when following python google-style-guide

Tags: python, google-style-guide

Google style guide requires to import modules. Say I have a non trivial class and several non-trivial derived classes. It seems that I have to put them all in the one file otherwise will have to use different prefixes when using them.

Personally I prefer one class per file. Is there a common idiom to avoid unnecessary large files?

E.g. can I rename several imports into one as long as there is no name conflicts?

```
import data_main as data
import data_derived_a as data
import data_derived_b as data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With modules, no, there's really no way of doing this that I know of. If you're happy to put your class in separate files within a package, though, you can import the individual classes in `__init__.py`, and your client modules can import them all at once, like so.

```
# mypackage/a.py
class A:
    pass

# mypackage/b.py
class B:
    pass

# mypackage/__init__.py
from .a import A
from .b import B

# mymodule.py
from mypackage import A, B
a = A()
b = B()

# Or mymodule.py
import mypackage as p
a = p.A()
b = p.B()
```

Comment: or you define `__all__` in `__init__.py` when you need more fine-grained control ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package))

Comment: can do 'import mypackage as p' and then use p.A and p.B ?

Comment: Yup, you can do that.